# How to align text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How would I align "Discord" with "Desktop"? I have tried `anchor="w"` and also `justify="left"`. I just cannot find the right argument.

```
 def settings():
      newWindow = Toplevel(root)
      newWindow.title("Settings")
      newWindow.configure(bd=25)
      alertFrequencyText = Label(newWindow, text="Desktop Notification Frequency (In 
  Minutes).", anchor="w")
      alertFrequencyText.grid(row=1, column=1)
      DiscordFrequency = Label(newWindow, text="Discord Alert Frequency", anchor="w")
      DiscordFrequency.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

[Picture to reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhXsa.png)

Comment: You want the `sticky='w'` option on the `.grid()` calls.  `anchor=` on a Label only matters if the Label is forced to have a larger size than the text actually needs, and that doesn't apply here.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you do much! Did not realise it was to be put inside `.grid()`. That solved my problem, thank you.